# PDOException: Query was empty

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I have a PDO PHP file making use of just one $_POST value stored on the `$data` array, and if an statement is true, a second value is added to that array to make a new query with two values:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("../conexionbbdd.php");    

    if($_SESSION['estado'] == 'activo' && $_SESSION['rol'] == '1'){

    $data = array(
        'us_id'   => $_POST['us_id'],
    );

    $selectUsers= "SELECT * FROM ws_users WHERE us_id= :us_id";
    $statementSelectUsers = $pdo->prepare($selectUsers);
    $statementSelectUsers->execute($data);
    $result = $statementSelectUsers->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $us_fk_ui_id =  $result['us_fk_ui_id'];

    if($us_fk_ui_id==='1'){

        $data['us_credits']=$_POST['us_credits'];

        $updateUser = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ws_users SET us_credits = :us_credits, us_access = '1' WHERE us_id = :us_id");
        $statementUpdateUser = $pdo->prepare($updateUser);     
        $statementUpdateUser->execute($data); 
    }
```

Everything goes fine untill the `$statementUpdateUser->execute($data);`  line (34), where I get the usual error

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065
>   Query was empty in C:\wamp\www**********\actions\ad_updateUserInfo.php on
>   line 34

As far as I've seen, this should be due to the unexistance of one of the placeholders on the array, but if I print the array values after the `$data['us_credits']=$_POST['us_credits'];` it seems to be correct, having the 2 expected values needed for my query:

> Array (
>       [0] => 2
>       [1] => 1.5 )

How could I check where the mistake is? There's no possibility of echoing the query as it is an object unable to transform on string.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$updateUser = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ws_users SET us_credits = :us_credits, us_access = '1' WHERE us_id = :us_id");
              ^^^ WTF??
```

You have to pay more attention to the code you write. Stack Overflow is NOT the service for finding typos for you.

Comment: No it is not. Solved.